# PHP display data

Tags: php

Guys we have a website that records the travel time of the vehicle. We have different kinds of reports. The problem is that our 2 reports is not the same on the last data. I think our problem is on the syntax on the display of our report.

here are sample screenshots of our reports. the KMLOG and the Daily Report. our problem is we need to display the output of the
]

```
if($endidling){
$total_idling=xtimediff($s_idling_date." ".$s_idling_time,$e_idling_date." ".$e_idling_time);
//if ($total_idling>=($entry['ilimit']*60)){



        if($s_idling_date==$e_idling_date){

        $data[$myCount]["xtype"] = "idling";
        $data[$myCount]["dur"] = sec2hms($total_idling);
        $data[$myCount]["sdate"] =date('M d',strtotime($s_idling_date));
        $data[$myCount]["stime"] =$s_idling_time." to ".$e_idling_time;
        $data[$myCount]["location"] = $location;
        $myCount +=1; 
        }
        else{
        //$data[$myCount]["stime"] =$s_idling_time." to ".$e_idling_time." of ".date('M d',strtotime($e_idling_date)) ;
            $day_def=def_date($s_idling_date,$e_idling_date);
            for($day=0;$day<=$day_def;$day++){

                if($day==0){
                    $ddur = xtimediff($s_idling_date." ".$s_idling_time,$s_idling_date." ".$gabi);
                    $data[$myCount]["stime"] =$s_idling_time." to ".$gabi;
                    $next_day=$s_idling_date;
                }
                elseif($day==$day_def){
                    $ddur = xtimediff($e_idling_date." ".$umaga,$e_idling_date." ".$e_idling_time);
                    $data[$myCount]["stime"] =$umaga." to ".$e_idling_time;
                    $next_day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($next_day . ' +1 day'));
                }
                else{
                    $ddur = xtimediff($s_idling_date." ".$umaga,$s_idling_date." ".$gabi);
                    $data[$myCount]["stime"] =$umaga." to ".$gabi;
                    $next_day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($next_day . ' +1 day'));
                }
                //if($day==0) $ddur= xtimediff($s_off_date." ".$s_off_time,$e_off_date." ".$e_off_time);
                $data[$myCount]["xtype"] = "idling";
                $data[$myCount]["dur"] = sec2hms($ddur);
                $data[$myCount]["sdate"] =date('M d',strtotime($next_day));
                $data[$myCount]["location"] = $location;
                $myCount +=1; 
            }

        }

    //}
    $endidling=false;
    $total_idling=0;
}
```

[image: Blockquote]

Comment: what about this code:-https://eval.in/674607   (just check code not the output)

Comment: still not working sir =(